# The console's original code line points to a problem

Tags: frontend, console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnsKo.png)
As shown in the figure, I see a console method in console. js
I call it in index. js

```
logN.primary('1', '2', {data: 1})
```

The console has printed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLnra.png)
This code points not to index. js but to console. js

I want it to point to the calling line of code

我修改了一下

```
// index.js
console.log(...logFunc("1", "2", { data: 1 }));
```

```
// console.js
const logFunc = (ns, msg, ...args) => {
  const color = "#50b5ff";
  return [
    `%c ${ns} %c ${msg} %c ${args.length ? "%o" : ""}`, `background:${color};border:1px solid ${color}; padding: 1px; border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px; color: #fff;`, `border:1px solid ${color}; padding: 1px; border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0; color: ${color};`,
    "background:transparent",
    ...args
  ];
};
```

This is feasible，But adding console. log is too troublesome. Is there any other way